# Fade In and Fade out Transition

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having a problem here,
I'm using a Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() to do a loop in my TimerTask
but the thing is, i can only do Fade In and i can't do the Fade Out
also I want to do When getting the new Image, it will fade In and slide in from right side and remove the Old Image and Slide out from left side while Fading Out.
Thanks

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * View
 */
public class View {
    private final Controller controller;
    private final Scene scene;
    private final Timer timer;
    private final TimerTask task;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public View(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;

        // add the necessary gui elements here
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(controller.getNextImage());
        FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(5000), imageView);
        ft.setFromValue(1.0);
        ft.setToValue(0.0);
        ft.play();
        vBox.getChildren().add(imageView);
        
        timer = new Timer(true);
        task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {

                    vBox.getChildren().clear();
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(controller.getNextImage());
                    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(5000), imageView);
                    ft.setFromValue(0.0);
                    ft.setToValue(1.0);
                    ft.setAutoReverse(true);
                    ft.play();
                    vBox.getChildren().add(imageView);

                });
            }

        };


        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 5000, 5000);
        scene = new Scene(vBox, 1150, 1000);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the scene for this view
     *
     * @return scene to this view
     */
    public Scene getScene() {
        return scene;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't mix awt and fx: remove the import of awt and anything that doesn't compile after doing so, don't use TimerTask: instead use fx "timing" support - to learn how to, do work through a tutorial on how to use fx animation/transition

Comment: [*Creating Transitions and Timeline Animations*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/animations.htm#JFXTE149).